# Change value of an input field by changing the select option

Tags: jquery

I would like to transmit own values e.g. (own value 0, own value 1 etc.) to an input field.
I tried with success `click(function () { })` but it does not work if you use tab navigation. So I thought it would be better tu use: `change(function () {` but it does not work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somaberlin/t019mvwq/1/)

Comment: Add relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the `change` event and then use the `value` property. You can also use `$(this).val()`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldt2bp56/)

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    $("#receiver").val("own value " + this.value);
});
```

EDIT: As per comment

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    var rec = $("#receiver");
    switch (+this.value) {
        case 0:
            rec.val("George");
            break;
        case 1:
            rec.val("Peter");
            break;
        case 2:
            rec.val("Jack");
            break;
    }
}).change();
```

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/75uvqdbf/)

Comment: I'm trying to pass own values (George, Peter, Jack) whether the first or last option was selected

`<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
 <option value="0" onclick="$('#receiver').val('George')">Please select</option>
 <option value="1" onclick="$('#receiver').val('Peter')">Option 1</option>
 <option value="2" onclick="$('#receiver').val('Jack')">Option 2</option>
</select>`

Comment: Then I would not ask a question here

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `change` event on the `select` and use its `val()` to set the text field value:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function(){
    $("#receiver").val($(this).val());
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/t019mvwq/3/

**Note:** I did not bother to reproduce the "own value" text as that looked like it was there for testing only.